# UIImage imageOrientation always reads opposite of way a picture is actually taken

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am encountering a strange issue where my `image.imageOrientation` always appear to be the opposite of the way the picture is taken. For example, when I hold my iPhone 5 upright to take a picture, the resulting `image.imageOrientation` always says "Landscape", and verse versa.

Here is my code for taking a picture, and checking the image's orientation:

```
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]){
        //A photo was taken
        self.imageTakenOrSelected = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];        
        if (self.imageTakenOrSelected.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
            NSLog(@"!------portrait");
        } else if (self.imageTakenOrSelected.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft || self.imageTakenOrSelected.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
            NSLog(@"!------landscape");
        }

        NSLog(@"self.imageTaken width: %f, and height %f", self.imageTakenOrSelected.size.width, self.imageTakenOrSelected.size.height);
    }
```

For example, when I take a picture upright, I would always get the NSLog that says "Landscape", and a read out of `self.imageTaken width: 2448.000000, and height 3264.000000` which seem to suggest that the image **is** taken in portrait.  What is going on here?

Thanks!